# font size resize on mobile?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I dev I simple page on HTML for the template, I put font-size ( 26px ) on my p, for desktop is good, but for mobile, I don't know why the size is smaller. i don't put media query

Does someone have an idea?

[mobile picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EosXm.png)
[desktop picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlnpE.png)

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" style="margin-top: 60px; margin-bottom: px" id="31006413">
    <div id="16215" class="col-lg-1 cellinsert" style="height: 0px;"></div>
    <div id="35209" class="col-lg-5 cellinsert" style="height: 300px;">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row " style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: px" id="32507865">
          <div id="99081" class="col-lg-12 cellinsert" style="height: auto; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1px -1px 27px 0px; border-radius: 20px; margin-bottom: 50px; background-color: rgb(15, 33, 46); min-height: 300px;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row " style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: px" id="6552410">
                <div id="149" class="col-lg-12 cellinsert" style="background-color: rgb(27, 44, 56); margin-top: -30px; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1px -1px 27px 0px; height: 60px;">
                  <div>
                    <p id="13857379" class="" style="font-size: 44px;">Title 1</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row " style="margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom: px" id="55398040">
                <div id="92491" class="col-lg-12 cellinsert" style="height: auto; font-size: 22px;">
                  <div>
                    <p id="96157133" class="" style="font-size: 26px; height: auto;">
                      00s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essent

                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide ALL relevant HTML and CSS. As the question currently sits, the issue cannot be reproduced.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and see [ask].

Comment: i cant put all code, stackoverflow give me error else

Answer (score 0):

Phone perspective will look super small when you look from your Computer Monitor.
You could also consider adding this to your code to make text bigger when viewed in small screens:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`